# Could not authenticate your SMTP account

Tags: wordpress, smtp, office365

My hosting is on GoDaddy (managed wordpress). I have a contact us form but when I try to end mail it says mail is sent successfully but I do not receive it. I am using wpforms and my email hosting provider is office 365. I am using this SMTP setting:-

SMTP host:- relay-hosting.secureserver.net
Encryption: None
SMTP Port:- 25

Can anybody tell me what is the problem?

Comment: This question has nothing whatsoever to do with programming. Please check where you post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/